# Using ojdbc5.jar for Oracle 12c server

Tags: oracle12c

Can a oracle 11g client ojdbc5.jar can be used to connect to Oracle 12c Server ? 
Will I run into any compatibility issues ?

Comment: Why are you *still* using Java 5?

Comment: [It isn't supported](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/enterprise-edition/jdbc-faq-090281.html#01_03). Will it work? Maybe, you'd have to try it. Will it work reliably? Probably not. Why not use [a later version](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/features/jdbc/index-091264.html)?